# grails mail: inline images working on localhost and not in test environment

Tags: debugging, grails, localhost, html-email

I'm adding inline images to my mails on localhost with:

```
inline 'footerImage', 'image/jpg', new File('./web-app/images/mailAssets/suchebottomre.gif').readBytes()
```

Which works fine.
When I deploy to my test environment I get this error:

```
Class
java.io.FileNotFoundException
Message
cannot use ./web-app/images/mailAssets/alert_header_pre.png as an attachment as it does not exist
```

with this log:

```
   Line | Method
->>  331 | inline      in grails.plugin.mail.MailMessageBuilder
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
|     20 | doCall      in de.docinsider.web.NotifierService$_contactUser_closure1
|     39 | sendMail .  in grails.plugin.mail.MailService
|     13 | contactUser in de.docinsider.web.NotifierService
|      7 | doCall . .  in de.docinsider.web.SendController$_closure1
|    195 | doFilter    in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.PageFragmentCachingFilter
|     63 | doFilter .  in grails.plugin.cache.web.filter.AbstractFilter
|   1145 | runWorker   in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor
|    615 | run . . . . in java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker
^    722 | run         in java.lang.Thread
```

How can this be avoided?

I also thaught about implementing a resourceloader with:

```
import org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware
import org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader

class SendController implements ResourceLoaderAware {
    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader
    def notifierService

    def index() { }
    def welcome = {
        notifierService.contactUser(params.username, params.email, params.message)
        render view:"/send/feedback", model:[name:params.username, message:params.message]
     }

     void setResourceLoader(ResourceLoader resourceLoader) {
        resourceLoader = resourceLoader
    }

}
```

This does also not work.

With:

```
 inline 'headerImage', 'image/jpg', resourceLoader.getResource('/images/mailAssets/header_top.png')
                inline 'footerImage', 'image/jpg', resourceLoader.getResource('/images/mailAssets/footer_bottom.gif')
```

In the service.

Comment: Shouldn't be `resourceLoader.getResource('/images/mailAssets/header_top.png').file.readBytes()`?

Comment: no this code is copy pasted from another location in our webapp where it is working, the only difference is, that it is called here from a service, in the other location the sendMail is called directly.

Comment: Please post the solution as an actual answer to this question and mark it as having solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I know this is an old thread, however I bumped into this same issue and found out that the server does not know the real path to the image, instead it uses the string as real path "./web-app/images/mailAssets/alert_header_pre.png".

Reading this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16225657/how-to-get-absolute-path-for-a-grails-application) will help you to get the real path.
Instead of:

```
inline 'footerImage', 'image/jpg', new File('./web-app/images/mailAssets/suchebottomre.gif').readBytes()
```

Use this:

```
inline 'footerImage', 'image/jpg', resourceLoader.getResource("/images/mailAssets/suchebottomre.gif").getFile()
```

You will need to `import org.springframework.core.io.Resource or org.springframework.core.io.ResourceLoader` and your controller implement `implements org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware` and declare `ResourceLoader resourceLoader`

Tested on:
Prod server: glassfish. 
Dev: Grails 2.3.7.