# How to get absolute path for a grails application

Tags: grails

I want the user to be able to download a file in my `web-app/images` folder

I've built an action like this:

```
def download () {
    def file = new File (params.filepath)

    if (file.exists()) {
        response.setContentType("application/octet-stream")
        response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "filename=${file.name}")
        response.outputStream << file.bytes
        return
    }
}
```

However when I pass in a file path `/images/myimage.jpeg` it is not finding that image.

**Question**

How can I get the absolute path where the grails application is deployed so that I can change my code to be like:

```
def file = new File (absolutePath + params.filepath)
```

**Note**

`System.properties['base.dir']` works locally but not when deployed to tomcat.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will work locally and in the deployed war:

```
class MyController implements org.springframework.context.ResourceLoaderAware {
  ResourceLoader resourceLoader 
  def download() {
    //org.springframework.core.io.Resource
    def someImage = resourceLoader.getResource("/images/someImage.png").getFile()
  }
}
```

Found it in a [mail user thread](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/How-to-load-file-in-images-directory-from-service-td1390324.html).

Comment: I am getting resourceLoader as null.. :(

Answer (score 1):

`def abolutePath =       request.getSession().getServletContext().getRealPath("/images/myimage.jpeg")`